# Trying to understand this set of Apache2 Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have the following Apache2 Rewrite rules and I am trying to decipher the meaning behind them:

```
1. RewriteEngine on
2. RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4
3. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
4. RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../tmp/stop.txt -f
5. RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
6. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=503,L]
```

1. Turn on `RewriteEngine`
2. If the requested address is not from the IP 1.2.3.4
3. If the requested URI does not contain a resource ends in .css or .gif or .jpg or .png
4. If the URI is requesting ../tmp/stop.txt (and that it is a file)
5. If the requested path is not a regular file
6. IF any of rule 2,3,4,5 is true, then display the 503 status page?

Am I close?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close :

- Step 2 : it is not the requested address, it is the client address (the IP address of the host making the request) :
  if client address is not 1.2.3.4
- Step 4 : as mentionned by @Florin Asavoaie : this just checks if file
  `../tmp/stop.txt` exists, no matter if it was requested or not.
- Step 5 : if requested file does not exist
- Step 6 : it is `AND` and not `OR` (All rules have to match). So :

  ```
  if (rule 2 is true) AND (rule 3 is true) AND (rule 4 is true) AND (rule 5 is true)
  {  
     Then return 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable (which works)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

On step 4 it shall just verify if that file exists or not, no matter if it was requested or not.

Did you actually test these? I am not sure if you can do a "redirect" with a code other than 3XX.

Comment: I saw this being set of rules being used on a production server and was really curious.